# How to get windows Session id using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Any ideas how get Win OS user session id from Google Chrome using JavaScript or any plugins for it ?

Task manager screenshot with session id:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=15rfklu&s=8#.VGS7h_mSzQk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your screenshot you are showing the session ID, but in the title of your question you mention the Process ID.  These are different things, but I'll assume you are actually interested in the Session ID.

The Session ID is a Windows concept, it is highly unlikely that it would ever be exposed by the browser.  So you will have to use the Win32 API to retrieve it.

And to use the Win32 API will require you to use Chrome's native messaging mechanism.

So the session ID could be retrieved using the following mechanism:

**1. Write a Win32 .EXE that retrieves the session ID for the current process.**

This will work because the native messaging application will always be launched in the same session as Chrome.

Write a routine that retrieves the session ID using the GetCurrentProcessId and ProcesssIdToSessionId API calls.

**2. Use chrome.nativeMessaging to launch the native messaging application and send it a command that will invoke the above code.**

You can read about writing a native messaging application here:  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging